# EnvironmentTagHelper renders itself on webpage including all content

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a dotnet 5 MVC project I maintain. Throughout subpages I use the environment tag helper to include some JS files, un-minified in development, and minified in production. I put these in a `@section` which is the included in my `_Layout.cshtml` file.

In some instances, when I run the project or deploy the site to Azure App Service, some pages work as expected and only load one version of the files. In other pages it puts the whole `<environment>` block thus including both un and minified versions, causing all my JS to run twice.

In my cshtml files I put this:

```
@section Scripts 
{
    <environment names="Development">
      <script src="/js/insights.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script src="/js/insights.min.js"></script>
    </environment>
}
```

Which in this instance produces this in my view

```
<script src="/js/insights.js"></script>
```

But when I include

```
@section Scripts 
{
    <environment names="Development">
        <script src="/js/users.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/notifications.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script src="/js/users.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/notifications.min.js"></script>
    </environment>
    ...
    some other inlined JS
}
```

I get this in my html

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="/js/users.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/notifications.js"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="/js/users.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/notifications.min.js"></script>
</environment>
```

In `_Layout.cshtml` I have

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

On the pages I have issues with, I've tried splitting the including scripts from the in line scripts which doesn't help. I've tried `names` and `includes` both of which are supported fields. Makes no difference. They aren't in different .net Areas, there are no special `@includes` on the page, I have `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` in my `ViewImports` file. But I do not understand why this has issues on a few pages.

Comment: Open F12 on the page you have a problem with. Is there any error message on the console?

Comment: @Chaodeng nope, no errors on the console. the html parses and ignores the `<environment>` tags and just loads the `<script>` tags